# Create a text file from Arduino using Processing

Tags: arduino, text-files, processing

Since Arduino cannot create a text file on its own, may I know how to create the text file using Processing?

1. Arduino serial input receives one character such as 's'.
2. Processing detects the 's' character from Arduino Serial Output and create a text file without any contents inside, with the title 'This is the text file.txt'
3. Thats it. Can anyone teach to me?

Appreciate your time spent reading and assisting me. thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to, you can create a text file using Arduino. A simple method is to add an SD card reader and use Arduino's [SD Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD) create and write to the text file you need.

In terms of receiving Arduino serial input, you should be able to start with [Arduino Serial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial) and [Processing Serial](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/index.html). Bare in mind Processing has examples too: **Examples > Libraries > Serial**.

To create a basic text file have a look at [saveStrings()](https://processing.org/reference/saveStrings_.html).
If you need to store formatted data (not just a bunch of text strings/sentences) you should also check out Processing support for [CSV](https://processing.org/reference/Table.html)(suitable for tabular data) and [JSON](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html)(suitable for nested tree data)

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeProfenza , appreciate your aid. But I want the text file to be saved inside my PC. Using SD card I need to disconnect and reconnect with PC to confirm if the test file had created or not.

Comment: No problem! The SD card is a nice option if you need your arduino to log data on it's own, independent of a computer. You can of course send data via Serial to Processing and simply write it to the computer's storage. For that, you've got all the links you need above. Feel free to vote/mark the answer if it was helpful ;)